# Get current position of ImageView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, collision-detection

This is my very first time trying to build an app in swift so please excuse the fact that my understanding is very limited.

---

After I have added an ImageView to my ViewController, connected a Pan Gesture Recognition and added the code to be able to move the ImageView, which works just fine, I now want to be able to get the current coordinates of the middle of my ImageView when moving it. The goal is to able to calculate the euclidian distance between the middle of the screen and the middle of the ImageView, in order to detect collision with a Circle that is around the ImageView, but for now, just being able to print the coordinates would really help me. Thanks for any advice or tips on how I could approach this.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var questImg: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func panMade(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.state == .began || sender.state == .changed {
                   let translation = sender.translation(in: sender.view)
                   let changeX = (sender.view?.center.x)! + translation.x
                   let changeY = (sender.view?.center.y)! + translation.y

                   sender.view?.center = CGPoint(x: changeX, y: changeY)
                   sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: sender.view)
    }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the location of UIImageView you can use frame.origin like below:

```
@IBAction func panMade(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .began || sender.state == .changed {
               let translation = sender.translation(in: sender.view)
               let changeX = (sender.view?.center.x)! + translation.x
               let changeY = (sender.view?.center.y)! + translation.y

               var coordX = questImg.frame.origin.x
               var coordY = questImg.frame.origin.y
               print(coordX + "," + coordY)

               sender.view?.center = CGPoint(x: changeX, y: changeY)
               sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: sender.view)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, so does that mean I can put that exact line inside my class and perhaps print(locoation) underneath to print the coordinates to my console? Because right now I'm getting errors when trying that...

Comment: But where in the above code would I put your line of code? Because when putting it beneath the declaration of questImg, I am getting 6 errors, the first being "Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'"

Comment: Do I not have to declare location somehow before? Sorry, I just don't understand what exactly is going on when with the syntax of your line because of my low level of understanding...

Comment: Try replacing panMade function with mine.

Comment: Thanks, now I get it. And now it prints coordinates perfectly.

Comment: Great All the best (Y)

Comment: Can I ask you one last question? Now I tried to change the image by using an if-statement inside the first if stament, like this: 
 "if sqrt((coordY - centerY)^2 + (coordX - centerX)^2) >= 100 {
                    questImg.image = UIImage(named: "2.png")
                    
            }"
But the error really makes no sense. Do you see whats wrong, per chance?

Comment: look for the types of coordY and centerY.